# Docker exists with message: "DEBU[0000] [hijack] End of stdout"

Tags: docker

I cannot run an image from dockerhub. It silently exists doing absolutely nothing.

```
$ docker run -it -v $(pwd):/build avivace/iosevka-build
```

If I run it with `-D` flag, it prints just one message:

```
$ docker -D run -it -v $(pwd):/build avivace/iosevka-build
DEBU[0000] [hijack] End of stdout
```

What does it mean? Why there is no other output?
I should say that yesterday it was running fine.

Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
OS: Linux Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: The DEBU message just means that stdout has been closed. That's not the reason why it exits.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this, in my case I had to override the CMD set in the Dockerfile by adding an entrypoint flag to the command:

```
--entrypoint /bin/bash
```

So you might try:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash -v $(pwd):/build avivace/iosevka-build
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that specific docker image which basically did nothing.
As for the message `DEBU[0000] [hijack] End of stdout` — as @HansKilian noted in the comments, it just means that stdout has been closed.